# Query GCP logger for distinct logs based on a field

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

Here is a sample log from my project in gcp logger

```
{
  "insertId": "________",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "stacktrace": "github.com_____",
    "level": "error",
    "msg": "could not update usage",
    "caller": "pkg/_______.go:118",
    "ts": ______.______,
    "requestID": "c7taeaa23akg00e8r0tg",
    "error": "write exception: write errors: [The field 'fieldName' must be an array but is of type null in document {_id: ObjectId('objectID001')}]"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name": "configName",
      "service_name": "serviceName",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "projectID",
      "revision_name": "revisionName"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-02-02T15:45:45.867386Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "____________"
  },
  "logName": "projects/_____/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-02-02T15:45:45.967298989Z"
}
```

The issue is there are so many of logs with this exact content.
My question is that is there query or a set of queries that can be used to retrieve one log with same `jsonPayload.error`.

For example, if there are 6 logs in which 3 of them have same `jsonPayload.error`, what I need to achieve is to get 4 logs where the duplicate logs will get cancelled out and only one among them will be at the output along with the other  3 different logs.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

Google's [Logging query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language) is a filtering mechanism. Applying a filter reduces the number of entries returned but it does not permit formatting the results to transform the entries.

To transform the results [you're gonna to need a bigger boat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I91DJZKRxs)... I recommend you consider using Google's [Cloud SDK command-line tools aka `gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk).

Using this you can filter logs using the queries that you've developed using Log Viewer:

```sh
gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

And (!) you can [transform (`--format`)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) the results:

```sh
gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
--format="${FORMAT}" \
--project=${PROJECT}"
```

> **NOTE** `gcloud`'s formatting does not appear to include unique|distinct functions and so we'll resort to using standard linux (`sort`|`uniq`) commands to achieve this.

As an example, a hopefully generic query of `cloud.audit.logging` operations:

```sh
PROJECT="..." # Your Project ID

# You would use "logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr\""
FILTER="logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\""

# You would use "value(jsonPayload.error)"
FORMAT="value(operation.producer)"

gcloud logging read  "${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="${FORMAT}" \
--limit=50 \
 > test.log

cat test.log | sort | uniq
```

Yields:

```
cloudfunctions.googleapis.com
compute.googleapis.com
container.googleapis.com
k8s.io
servicemanagement.googleapis.com
serviceusage.googleapis.com
```

> **NOTE** `gcloud logging read "${FILTER}"` submits the filter to the platform and is run "service-side". The results (which may be large) are then e.g. `--format`'ted client-side and this can be time/processor-consuming. In the example above, to save repeatedly retrieving the data from the server and then piping it through `sort` and `uniq`, it's more efficient to dump the logs into a file first. I've also used `--limit` to artificially restrict the number of results returned for testing purposes. You may want to use a time filter or something other constraint.

Because you referenced `jsonPayload`, You can `gcloud ... --format=json(...)` too in order to extract JSON-formatted logs. As described above, `gcloud` includes formatting functionality but, also as shown above, sometimes it's easiest to use general-purpose tools. In this case, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) provides powerful ways to transform JSON.

```sh
gcloud logging read  "${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="${FORMAT}" \
--limit=50 \
> test.json

cat test.json | jq -r unique
```

Yields:

```
[
  null,
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "compute.googleapis.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "container.googleapis.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "k8s.io"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "servicemanagement.googleapis.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": {
      "producer": "serviceusage.googleapis.com"
    }
  }
]
```